Issue representing weeks in a quarter
I'm trying to write a script that will return the first day of the quarter and the last day of the week i.e., 04/01-04/06, the first and last day of every week in the quarter e.g., 06/23-06-29, and the last week of the quarter e.g., 06/30 or 12/29-12/31.
SELECT [Date_Key]
      ,[Date]
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofWeek AND LastDateofWeek 
            THEN FORMAT([Month], '00') + '/' + FORMAT([Day], '00') 
            ELSE '' 
        END AS [Week_Date_Axis]
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofWeek AND LastDateofWeek 
            THEN [Month] * 100 + [Day] 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS [Week_Date_Axis_SK]
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofMonth AND LastDateofMonth 
            THEN FORMAT([Month], '00') + '/' + FORMAT([Day], '00') 
            ELSE '' 
        END AS [Month_Date_Axis]
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofMonth AND LastDateofMonth 
            THEN [Month] * 100 + [Day] 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS [Month_Date_Axis_SK]  
----this section is where I'm having a hard time
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofQuarter AND LastDateofQuarter 
            THEN FORMAT(DATEPART(MONTH, dateadd(DAY,0,[FirstDateofWeek])), '00') + '/' + FORMAT(DATEPART(DAY, dateadd(DAY,0,[FirstDateofWeek])), '00') + '-' + 
                 FORMAT(DATEPART(MONTH, dateadd(DAY,0,[FirstDateofWeek])), '00') + '/' + FORMAT(DATEPART(DAY, dateadd(DAY,0,[LastDateofWeek])), '00')
            ELSE '' 
        END AS [Quarter_Date_Axis]
    ---- End of hard time
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofQuarter AND LastDateofQuarter 
            THEN [Month] * 100 + [Day] 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS [Quarter_Date_Axis_SK]
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofYear AND LastDateofYear 
            THEN FORMAT(DATEPART(MONTH, dateadd(DAY, 0, [FirstDateofMonth])), '00') + '/' + FORMAT(DATEPART(DAY, dateadd(DAY, 0, [FirstDateofMonth])), '00') 
            ELSE '' 
        END AS [Year_Date_Axis]
      , CASE 
            WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN FirstDateofYear AND LastDateofYear 
            THEN [Month] * 100 + [Day] 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS [Year_Date_Axis_SK]
      ,[Day]
      ,[Weekday]
      ,[WeekDayName]
      ,[WeekDayName_Short]
      ,[WeekDayName_FirstLetter]
      ,[DOWInMonth]
      ,[DayOfYear]
      ,[WeekOfMonth]
      ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATE) AS [WeekOfYear]
      ,[Month]
      ,[MonthName]
      ,[MonthName_Short]
      ,[MonthName_FirstLetter]
      ,[Quarter]
      ,[QuarterName]
      ,[Year]
FROM [dbo].[Tbl_Date_Dim]
WHERE [Year] = YEAR(GETDATE())

----Available date dim columns
       [Date]
      ,[Day]
      ,[DaySuffix]
      ,[Weekday]
      ,[WeekDayName]
      ,[WeekDayName_Short]
      ,[WeekDayName_FirstLetter]
      ,[DOWInMonth]
      ,[DayOfYear]
      ,[WeekOfMonth]
      ,[WeekOfYear]
      ,[Month]
      ,[MonthName]
      ,[MonthName_Short]
      ,[MonthName_FirstLetter]
      ,[Quarter]
      ,[QuarterName]
      ,[Year]
      ,[MMYYYY]
      ,[MonthYear]
      ,[FinancialYear]
      ,[FinancialQuarter]
      ,[FinancialMonth]
      ,[FirstDateofYear]
      ,[LastDateofYear]
      ,[FirstDateofQuarter]
      ,[LastDateofQuarter]
      ,[FirstDateofMonth]
      ,[LastDateofMonth]
      ,[FirstDateofWeek]
      ,[LastDateofWeek]
      ,[CurrentYear]
      ,[CurrentQuarter]
      ,[CurrentMonth]
      ,[CurrentWeek]
      ,[CurrentDay]

Our weeks start on Sundays, so I'm returning 03/31 (A Sunday) for the start of the quarter and that's wrong, should be 04/01 (A Monday). I'm also not getting the month to rollover e.g., 05/26-05/01 should be 05/26-06/01, and finally the last week of the quarter is showing as 06/30-06/06 when it should be just 06/30. Any thoughts or tips would be helpful, thanks
Return from script

I'm assuming you have some kind of date table? If so what colum,ns are contained in it and where do FirstDateofQuarter, LastDayOfQuarter come from? Finally, don't format dates in your code, leave that to the presentation layer (Power BI in your case I assume).

Yes, we have a date dim table with First/Last DayOfQuarter. I believe the formatting is happening in t-sql because the way the tables are designed in PowerBI, essentially need to create 4 formats for Current Week, Current Month, Current Quarter, and Current Year and I don't believe PowerBI is flexible enough to do that without bookmarks and we aren't using those for this project. But, I will raise that concern to my senior data visualization devs.

It's probably worth showing a sample of your date tale with the relevant dates and associated columns and show the whole query (or at least the pertinent parts of it). If you Edit your question and add the extra info I'm sure somebody will be able to answer.

Please provide a [mre] including sample data and desired results (as table markdown not images).

On some wild guesses and without any testing I suggest this:
;WITH strings AS(
SELECT
  Year
  ,Quarter
  ,WeekOfYear
  ,string = FORMAT(MIN(Date), 'MM/dd', 'en-US') + '-' + FORMAT(MAX(Date), 'MM/dd', 'en-US') 
FROM Tbl_Date_dim
GROUP BY
  Year
  ,Quarter
  ,WeekOfYear
)
SELECT
  d.*
  ,s.string
FROM Tbl_Date_dim d
JOIN strings s
  ON d.Year = s.Year
     AND d.Quarter = s.Quarter
     AND d.WeekOfYear = s.WeekOfYear

I take it that the only field giving You trouble is the string that's based on the boundaries of the potentially partial weeks of the quarter.
On second thought, this might work, too:
SELECT
  *
  ,string =         FORMAT(MIN(Date)OVER(PARTITION BY Year, Quarter, WeekOfYear, 'MM/dd', 'en-US') 
            + '-' + FORMAT(MAX(Date)OVER(PARTITION BY Year, Quarter, WeekOfYear, 'MM/dd', 'en-US') 
FROM Tbl_Date_dim 

